# Instantiate Fields Dynamically in an User defined object

Tags: java

Need to create an object dynamically using the field names passed in the method parameter.

Something like..

```
public void createDisplay(List<String> fields) {
//fetch fields names
//create an object in java using the fields passed
//assign values to the dynamically created fields.
}
```

Or

```
public void createDisplay(Schema schema) {
//create an object in java using the schema
//assign values to the dynamically created fields.
}
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: To be clear:  you want to create new classes at *runtime*?

Comment: Yes, Makoto. New Class at runtime.

Comment: What's wrong with `TreeMap<String, Object>` where your first parameter is the **fieldName** and the second parameter (`Object`) is the **parameter value**?  That's the point of the data-structures found in `java.util.*` **NOTE:** You could also use `HashMap<String, Object>` - or even simply two parallel Vector's - I personally avoid creating specialized Java Objects almost 95% of the time / when possible - but then again, I often use `java.io.Serializable`, which means never worrying about object UUID's.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please lease a criticism along with your vote. To my mind, this is a smart worthy Question for anyone exploring Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: @BasilBourque:  Dynamic code generation has next to nothing to do with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little vague. If you really want fully initialized object to be created from your method then I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
public void createDisplay(List<String> fields) {
//Iterate over the list do null checking wherever required
//call parameterized constructor of your class and pass values in the loop and keep on adding them
//change the return type of method from void to the object/list of object 
//you want and return it from this method
}
```

Comment: There is no class. that is the point. You have some field names. Create a class dynamically. Instantiate it dynamically. Use it.

Comment: It is something like GraphQL. You have a dynamic schema.

Comment: @Sambhav As far as I know reflection allows you to create instances and let's you call the methods but you cannot create a class using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing, this isn't really worth it at runtime.  It may be more valuable to invest this energy into a compile-time solution instead.

There's a library out there called [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net) which has the ability to dynamically generate types, but I'm not convinced that there's much in the way of utility in that regard, since you want to create a *proper* type in the system dynamically.  The biggest issues you would face are:

- If you have more than one class loader active, you run the very real risk of running into tough-to-diagnose bugs at runtime which would bring your application to its knees.  For reference, [Tomcat has *four*.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)
- If you wanted to get compile-time safety of the class that was dynamically created, that'd be impossible - by default, ByteBuddy generates classes which have a different name to what you're expecting.
- There's more headache in debugging and diagnosing dynamically generated code since there's no real way to accomplish static analysis.

I would ***strongly*** recommend that you look into a compile-time solution instead.  Runtime solutions are attractive for their flexibility, but Java goes out of its way to be *in*flexible.

Comment: There is simply no reason I can think of not to use a **Java Generic** Type from java.util for these `fields`.  I typed my solution, but somebody decided I needed a "down-vote" - so....  **Unfortunately** (for them), everybody should know that parallel arrays and / or hash-table solutions were literally created in Java for this type of problem.   Since there is absolutely no way to "invent method names" at runtime, just using method's that look up the value of the fields in the Object in a **`Hashtable`** or **`TreeMap`** (Table) is one of the fundamentals in Java.

Comment: Um...why are you commenting about the downvote (in general), and why are you doing so on my answer @RalphTorello?

Comment: I would **strongly** argue that this answer does not elucidate Java's strength at all!  In a word - it is **incorrect**.  Java's generic's solve this type of problem very well - **I use them all day long**. :)

Comment: @RalphTorello:  Using generics is not the same as generating bytecode at runtime.  Generics add *compile time* support anyway.  You're playing checkers and we're talking about Go.