# Create an object class dynamically in java based on input

Tags: java, class, object

I want to create an object class based on my input.
For example, there's a cat class. The attributes are cat breeds.
Normally, it would be like...

```
private String americanShorthair;
private String ragDoll;
private String persian;
//getters and setters
```

Now I want it to be dynamic based on the input and it's not set in the stone. I want to have different breeds based on the parameters. If I want scottishFold, I can add it in the parameter. Can I do this in Java? Thanks

edit: to make it more clear
I have this collection [americanShorthair, ragDoll, persian]

I want the class defining an object to have these attributes, so it would look like this:

```
public class Cat(){
private String americanShorthair;
private String ragDoll;
private String persian;
//getters and setters
}
```

The collection is based on input, so if it's [name, age, sex], the object should change correspondingly, and it should look like this...

```
public class Cat(){
private String name;
private String age;
private String sex;
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look up some tutorials on Java inheritance, as that is the best way to accomplish what I **think** you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. the closest was https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-in-java/

Comment: This isn't how it would normally be at all; those would be *values* of `String breed`.

Comment: but instead of an int and string, my parameter is an array, so it's like [americanShorthair, ragDoll, persian]

Comment: @chrylis it is just an example. I just want some names from an array to be my attribute.

Comment: That is a *completely* different scenario from having lots of *different* properties. Perhaps you're looking for something like a `List<String> breeds`.

Comment: actually I want to make all breeds different attributes. so the result would be like in the code. I looked everywhere I can't find a solution to this...

Comment: An object and class are two different things. If you don't know the difference, stop coding and do some study such as the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: @AndyLi You used the phrase “object class”. You obviously are missing some key concepts about OOP given the nature of your question. And watch the attitude when asking for free help.

Comment: @BasilBourque maybe I phrased it wrong. I learned java in a different language, but I think you should figure out what I mean with the example. I meant a class defining an object. A cat class can describe everything about a cat. Here I want it to define the breeds. You don't have to get into the technicality here.

Comment: Actually, it is *your* job to make clear what you mean with your example.

Comment: Definitely agree with @BasilBourque. We are all volunteers here; it is not our job to try and guess what you might mean by your questions and code. Please review the [ask] article in the SO help page. Also, taking the [tour] before posting another question would be advised.

Comment: @Zephyr i thought my question was clear

Comment: @AndyLi - I'm afraid it is not clear at all...

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: @BasilBourque I think the word I was looking for was "entity", a class defining an object

Comment: You can't create a completely dynamic class like this in Java (without great pain). Normally you'd use a Map (eg HashMap) for this purpose.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. that is what I thought. It would help me a lot if I could.

Comment: Your problem does not seem to be a real world problem. If it is not real I cannot imagin why maps are not acceptable. If it is a real world problem, please be more concrete. I hardly can imagine a real problem, where I need classes based on input.

Comment: @CoronA the actual scenario is I need to draw data from a table and use the values of a certain column to make a new table. The values from the old table become columns of the new table. I'm using myBatis to insert data, but I can't do that without encapsulating objects. I need dynamic entities.

Comment: So it seems that the schema of the tables to migrate is fixed. Then you can create a class per table and each row gets an instance of the associated class. If you want keep the iteration over the tables generic, you will have to fall back to maps, then do not use mybatis for this task.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of [*Instantiate Fields Dynamically in an User defined object*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52823171/642706)

Answer (score 1):

Define a class with member fields for each kind of information you want to track.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CatBreed {
    public String breed;

    // Constructor

    public CatBreed ( String breed ) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "CatBreed{ " +
                "breed='" + breed + '\'' +
                " }";
    }

}
```

Create a collection to hold some instances (objects) of that class.

```
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        List < CatBreed > breeds = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
        breeds.add( new CatBreed( "Persian" ) );
        breeds.add( new CatBreed( "Maine Coon" ) );
        breeds.add( new CatBreed( "Russian Blue" ) );

        System.out.println( breeds );
    }
```

> [CatBreed{ breed='Persian' }, CatBreed{ breed='Maine Coon' }, CatBreed{ breed='Russian Blue' }]

If you are representing the breed on particular individual cats, define a `Cat` class in a similar manner.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cat {
    String breed;
    String name;
    Year yearOfBirth;

    public Cat ( String breed , String name , Year yearOfBirth ) {
        this.breed = breed;
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Cat{ " +
                "breed='" + breed + '\'' +
                " | name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | yearOfBirth=" + yearOfBirth +
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        List < Cat > cats = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
        cats.add( new Cat( "Persian" , "Fluffy" , Year.of( 2011 ) ) );
        cats.add( new Cat( "Maine Coon" , "Spot" , Year.of( 2012 ) ) );
        cats.add( new Cat( "Russian Blue" , "Big Boy" , Year.of( 2013 ) ) );

        System.out.println( cats );
    }
}
```

> [Cat{ breed='Persian' | name='Fluffy' | yearOfBirth=2011 }, Cat{ breed='Maine Coon' | name='Spot' | yearOfBirth=2012 }, Cat{ breed='Russian Blue' | name='Big Boy' | yearOfBirth=2013 }]

If all the breeds are known at compile-time, use an enum. The enum facility in Java is far more useful, flexible, and powerful than in other platforms. Using an enum provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cat {
    enum Breed { PERSIAN, MAINE_COON, RUSSIAN_BLUE }

    Breed breed;
    String name;
    Year yearOfBirth;

    public Cat ( Breed breed , String name , Year yearOfBirth ) {
        this.breed = breed;
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Cat{ " +
                "breed='" + breed + '\'' +
                " | name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | yearOfBirth=" + yearOfBirth +
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        List < Cat > cats = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
        cats.add( new Cat( Breed.PERSIAN , "Fluffy" , Year.of( 2011 ) ) );
        cats.add( new Cat( Breed.MAINE_COON , "Spot" , Year.of( 2012 ) ) );
        cats.add( new Cat( Breed.RUSSIAN_BLUE , "Big Boy" , Year.of( 2013 ) ) );

        System.out.println( cats );
    }
}
```

> [Cat{ breed='PERSIAN' | name='Fluffy' | yearOfBirth=2011 }, Cat{ breed='MAINE_COON' | name='Spot' | yearOfBirth=2012 }, Cat{ breed='RUSSIAN_BLUE' | name='Big Boy' | yearOfBirth=2013 }]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for. I don't want "breeds", I want them as separate attributes. Sorry if I misled you. I want attributes to be dynamic, not the elements in an attribute. If i have 3 elements in the collection, The cat class should have 3 attribute. If I have 4 in the collection, the cat should have 4. Please see the code in the question.

Comment: Okay, scratch the idea of "breeds". I was only trying to simplify things but apparently i've made it harder to understand. Say my collection is [name, age, color], I want exactly these as the attributes of the object. The list is mutable so I can have [name, sex, breed] if I want. The attributes of the object is based on whatever is in the collection.